# Straight edge between nodes with break

Tags: tikz-pgf, edge

I would like to modify this MWE so that the edge connecting the two nodes is a straight line with a break that allows the edge connect to (b.north west) with a 135° angle. The other end of the edge connect to (a.south west) exiting to the right.
The result should be like the lines connecting the nodes of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177249/decision-trees-in-tikz), but I don't want to use the same package.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {a};
\node (b) [right of=a, below of=a, xshift=2cm] {b};
\draw (a.south west)  to [in=135, out=0] (b.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Why don't you want to use **forest**? It is very, very good. You can do it, probably, using one of the other tree packages or even just manually. But why make it difficult when somebody else already invented wheels and is providing them to all who want them for free?

Comment: Is forest only used for creating tree graph? In that case, I can't use it since I need to picture a more complicated graph.

Comment: Well, it depends. Yes, it draws trees. However, you can also draw stuff in addition to the tree, including stuff you specify within the tree or after the tree using regular TikZ. And sometimes you can fake non-tree graphs, too, when that's more convenient. Which isn't to say that it is suitable for your case as I don't know what your requirements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**forest** is much easier, but you can do everything manually if you prefer:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {a};
  \node (b) [right of=a, below of=a, xshift=2cm] {b};
  \draw (a.south west) -- (a.south west -| {$(b.north west) + (135:10mm)$}) --   (b.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: non-forest connections]

Comment: That's a better solution. However, consider that in b the node shape is a diamond, as in  

\node (b) [draw, diamond, right of=a, below of=a, xshift=0.5cm] {b};

 (add also \usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric} )The slope of the edge seems a bit off, it doesn't seem to touch the side of the diamond perpendicularly, isn't it? Also, it changes if I put 5mm in place of 10mm. How can I fix it?

Comment: I can fix with
 
\draw (a.south west) -- (a.south west -| {$(b) + (135:10mm)$}) --(b.north west); 

i.e. using b and not b. north west to evaluate the coordinates in $...$

Comment: That will take the angle from the default anchor for the node `b`. It just depends where you want the 135 measured from. You said the `north west`, so that's what I used. If you want something different, obviously you can change it accordingly.

Comment: Now that I understand better how calc works, I see that to get a line perpendicular to the north west side of the diamond, the correct line is \draw (a.south west) -- (a.south west -| {$(b) + (180:10mm)$}) --(b.north west);

Comment: There are simpler ways, but yes, that would work. But that is not what you asked how to do in this question, is it?

Answer (score 2):

One can also borrow the code of `-|` operator. I should call it `-\` but then I need to hack the parser of Ti*k*Z. (`\tikz@lineto`, line 2699 of `tikz.code.tex`)

Notice that there are three changes in the definition of `\tikz@@hv@lineto`. The third corresponds to `-|` between explicit coordinates. The first two correspond to the node case.

Notice also that I did nothing about `\tikz@timer`. Thus `pos=.5`, `midway`, or their family is not going to work properly.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=9]{standalone}

\makeatletter

\def\tikz@@hv@lineto#1{%
  \edef\tikz@timer@start{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}%
  \pgf@xc=\tikz@lastx% NEW LINE
  \pgf@yc=\tikz@lasty%
  \tikz@make@last@position{#1}%
  \edef\tikz@tangent{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\pgf@yc}}%
  \tikz@flush@moveto@toward{\pgfqpoint{\tikz@lastx}{\pgf@yc}}\pgf@x\pgf@yc%
  \iftikz@shapeborder%
    % ok, target is a shape. have to work now:
    {%
      %\pgf@process{\pgfpointshapeborder{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{\pgfqpoint{\tikz@lastx}{\pgf@yc}}}% Replace by the following
      \pgf@process{\pgfpointshapeborder{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{\pgfpoint{\tikz@lastx-sign(\tikz@lastx-\pgf@xc)*abs(\pgf@yc-\tikz@lasty)}{\pgf@yc}}} % NEW LINE
      \tikz@make@last@position{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}%
      %\tikz@path@lineto{\pgfqpoint{\tikz@lastx}{\pgf@yc}}% Replace by the following
      \tikz@path@lineto{\pgfpoint{\tikz@lastx-sign(\tikz@lastx-\pgf@xc)*abs(\pgf@yc-\tikz@lasty)}{\pgf@yc}} % NEW LINE
      \tikz@path@lineto{\tikz@last@position}%
      \xdef\tikz@timer@end@temp{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}% move out of group
    }%
    \let\tikz@timer@end=\tikz@timer@end@temp%
    \edef\tikz@moveto@waiting{\tikz@shapeborder@name}%    
  \else%
    %\tikz@path@lineto{\pgfqpoint{\tikz@lastx}{\pgf@yc}}% Replace by the following
    \tikz@path@lineto{\pgfpoint{\tikz@lastx-sign(\tikz@lastx-\pgf@xc)*abs(\pgf@yc-\tikz@lasty)}{\pgf@yc}} % NEW LINE
    \tikz@path@lineto{\tikz@last@position}%
    \edef\tikz@timer@end{\noexpand\pgfqpoint{\the\tikz@lastx}{\the\tikz@lasty}}% move out of group
  \fi%
  \let\tikz@timer=\tikz@timer@hvline%
  \tikz@scan@next@command%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(a){a};
        \node(b)[below right of=a, xshift=2cm]{b};
        \node(c)[below left of=a, xshift=-2cm]{c};
        \node(d)[above right of=a, xshift=2cm]{d};
        \node(e)[above left of=a, xshift=-2cm]{e};
        \draw(a.south east)-|(b.north west);
        \draw(a.south west)-|(c.north east);
        \draw(a.north east)-|(d.south west);
        \draw(a.north west)-|(e.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node(a){a};
        \node(b)[below right of=a, xshift=2cm]{b};
        \node(c)[below left of=a, xshift=-2cm]{c};
        \node(d)[above right of=a, xshift=2cm]{d};
        \node(e)[above left of=a, xshift=-2cm]{e};
        \draw(a)-|(b);
        \draw(a)-|(c);
        \draw(a)-|(d);
        \draw(a)-|(e);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Won't this work only if you want connections of this type for all `-|` connections? That is, you can't also use regular `-|` paths?

Comment: @cfr I am saying that `-|` is a good start. One can then rename it as `-/` or `/-`, and modify Ti*k*Z's "if-switcher". Now we can write `\draw(A)--(B)-|(C)-/(D);`

Comment: Oh, I see. OK. That makes sense. Certainly if you want a lot of these.

Answer (score 1):

You can cook up your own `to path`. Here `mypath` takes an argument as to how much of the path should be drawn as a straight before breaking. If set too high obviously it will over draw but in general should be OK.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mypath/.style={
    to path={let \p1=($(\tikztostart)-(\tikztotarget)$),
                 \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2 = {(\x1<0?1:2)}
                 in 
                 -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!180*\n2-\n1:(\tikztotarget)$)
                 -- (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes
          }
      }]

\node (a) {a};
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {20,130,245,330}{
  \node[diamond,draw] (b-\xi) at (\x:3cm) {b};
  \draw (a.south west) to[mypath={min(0.5,rnd)}] (b-\xi);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also please have a look at [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz/9391) to avoid the deprecated syntax.