# Forest, asymetry of branches

Tags: forest

Consider answer of Gonzalo Medina on question [decision trees in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177249/decision-trees-in-tikz/177254). For my learning process proposes I slightly modified it:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{
EL/.style={%Edge Labels
  midway,
  #1,% <--- position: "EL=above" or "EL=below"
  font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
  text=teal,
  text width=1.5cm,
  align=center,
            }
}

\begin{document}
%%%% modified version
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  grow=east,
  draw=teal,
  circle,
  line width=0.4pt,
  parent anchor=east,
  child anchor=west,
  edge={draw=teal,very thin},
%  edge label={\Huge\color{black}}, % <-- this seems to haven't any influence on tree
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- 
      ([xshift=-17mm].child anchor) -- % intermediate point
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=19mm,            % <-- *l*: level distance
}
[,rectangle, 
  s sep=8mm,            % <-- *s*: sibling distance
  [,edge label={node[EL=below]{option1}}
    [,edge label={node[EL=below]{a longer text goes here}}
    ]
    [,edge label={node[EL=above]{text}}
    ]
  ]
  [B,edge label={node[EL=above]{option2}}
    [,edge label={node[EL=below]{a longer text goes here}}
    ]
    [,edge label={node[EL=above]{text}}
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
    \end{document}
```

Why decision tree become asymmetric regarding to horizontal symmetry line through nodes, if I add some test in nodes? For example, at node B the next level upper branches have smaller distance from center horizontal  line through node than lower one. I tested this with forest 2.0.

[image]

Comment: You are right about the `edge label` doing nothing, by the way. I'm slightly surprised it doesn't give an error, but it certainly shouldn't do anything else.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34850/discussion-between-cfr-and-crocket (It is not really a discussion between me and crocket. The room has been hijacked and I've been discussing Forest 2 there with Sašo Živanović. It is a little one-sided today, but has been much more interesting over the weekend.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution. The documentation is rather misleading since it isn't true the the value of `anchor` only matters when the node has a sibling.

[However, it is not saying what my earlier version of this answer claimed. So if you read that, I was being an idiot and you should ignore it.]

The default value of `calign` is `center` which aligns the parent's `anchor` with the midpoint between the children's `anchor`s. And the default value of `anchor` is `base`.

Here's a picture:

[image: default alignment demo]

So the alignment we'd like requires either changing the `anchor` of the parent and children or using a non-default value for `calign`.

In the first case, we could do something like this, setting `anchor=center` for the tree:

[image: anchor=center]

or `anchor=parent` (i.e. `west` in this case):

[image: anchor=parent]

or `anchor=children` (i.e. `east`) here:

[image: anchor=children]

The anchor `children` always faces the children of the node (or where the children would be); `parent` faces the parent of the node (or where the parent would be).

Alternatively, we could alter `calign`. For example `calign=edge midpoint`. However, this doesn't work quite as I expected:

[image: align midpoints of edges]

I can't figure out exactly where the children's child anchors are in this case but they seem to be wherever-TikZ-would-take-a-path-to relative to wherever you are comping from or going to.

But even setting `parent anchor=east` and `child anchor=west` for the tree doesn't really help:

[image: align midpoints of edges?]

So I would change `anchor` for the tree, as I do below, regardless of what else seems desirable. This seems to give good results in this case.

(However, for non-circular nodes, something other than `center` does often make sense.)

I've also make a couple of other tiny modifications which you may (or may not) be interested in. In particular, I've changed the anchors so that they are not direction-dependent. So you can change the direction of growth and the `parent` and `child` anchors should still make sense. I've also had the package figure out whether the labels on the edges should go above or below the lines.

But only

```
    anchor=children,% work around alignment issue
```

is really making any difference to the result.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
% Zarko's modification of Gonzalo Medina's answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177254/
\tikzset{%
  EL/.style={%
    midway,
    #1,
    font=\scriptsize\sffamily,
    text=teal,
    text width=1.5cm,
    align=center,
  }
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw=teal,
    line width=0.4pt,
    edge={draw=teal,very thin},
    grow=east,
    circle,
    parent anchor=children,
    child anchor=parent,
    edge path'={
       (!u.parent anchor) -- ([xshift=-17mm].child anchor) -- (.child anchor)
    },
    l sep=19mm,
    anchor=children,% work around alignment issue
  },
  before typesetting nodes={%
    where n=1{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[EL=below]{#1}}
    }{%
      edge label/.wrap value={node[EL=above]{#1}}
    }
  }
  [, rectangle, s sep=8mm,
    [, edge label={option1}
      [, edge label={a longer text goes here}
      ]
      [, edge label={text}
      ]
    ]
    [B, edge label={option2}
      [, edge label={a longer text goes here}
      ]
      [, edge label={text}
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: workaround alignment issue]

Code for demos:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={% default calign, anchor
    grow=east,
    draw
  }
  [
    [B, tikz={%
      \draw [densely dotted, blue] (!u.base) -- (.base);
      \draw [densely dotted, red] (.base) -- ($(!1.base)!1/2!(!l.base)$) edge (!1.base) -- (!l.base);
    }
      [][]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={% default calign, anchor=center
    grow=east,
    draw,
    anchor=center
  }
  [
    [B, tikz={%
      \draw [densely dotted, blue] (!u.center) -- (.center);
      \draw [densely dotted, red] (.center) -- ($(!1.center)!1/2!(!l.center)$) edge (!1.center) -- (!l.center);
    }
      [][]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={% default calign, anchor=parent
    grow=east,
    draw,
    anchor=parent
  }
  [
    [B, tikz={%
      \draw [densely dotted, blue] (!u.parent) -- (.parent);
      \draw [densely dotted, red] (.parent) -- ($(!1.parent)!1/2!(!l.parent)$) edge (!1.parent) -- (!l.parent);
    }
      [][]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={% default calign, anchor=children
    grow=east,
    draw,
    anchor=children
  }
  [
    [B, tikz={%
      \draw [densely dotted, blue] (!u.children) -- (.children);
      \draw [densely dotted, red] (.children) -- ($(!1.children)!1/2!(!l.children)$) edge (!1.children) -- (!l.children);
    }
      [][]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={% calign=edge midpoint, default anchor
    grow=east,
    draw,
    calign=edge midpoint,
    parent anchor=east,
    child anchor=west,
  }
  [
    [B, tikz={%
      \draw [densely dotted, blue] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor);
      \draw [densely dotted, red] (.parent anchor)  -- ($(!1.child anchor)!1/2!(!l.child anchor)$) edge (!1.child anchor) -- (!l.child anchor);
    }
      [][]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's actually the documentation of `anchor` that is unclear. So setting `anchor` to `center`, `west` or `children` is not just a workaround, but *the* solution.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up east and west above: in an east growing tree, east=children and west=parent.

Comment: About s-alignment of children in an east growing tree: consider the following tree: `\begin{forest}for tree={grow=east,draw}[[,anchor=west][,anchor=east]]\end{forest}`

Comment: Cleaned up a little ...

Comment: @cfr, thank you for your answer with exhaustive explanation. For understanding all I need to repeat all given examples. Hopefully I will do this during day :-)

Comment: And I will fix `calign=edge midpoint`, as that example shows a bug.

Comment: @SašoŽivanović Ah! Thank you. I was reluctant to assume that I wasn't just misreading something again ;).